# how to know partitions size

Tags: fdisk

I entered `sudo fdisk -l` now I want to know how much of my hard disk belong to this partition:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda2       156264318   273474494    58605088+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands,

```
sudo fdisk -s /dev/sda2
```

From `fdisk --help`

```
fdisk -s <partition>    -  give partition size(s) in blocks
```

OR

```
lsblk /dev/sda2
```

SIZE field will display the partition size.